# Statistical symbols: should greek letters be used for population or for a sample?

Tags: statistics, notation

When finding mean and the stansard deviation, do you use the Greek symbols for a population, or a sample. When do you use "s" and xbar, for a population, or a sample?

(I am taking AP Statistics)

Comment: please help? :)

Comment: The population values generally use Greek letters; the sample values, Roman letters.

Comment: ok, i hope you are right ;) lol thank you

Comment: I think of $\bar{X}$ and $s^2_X$ as unbiased estimators of $\mu_X$ and $\sigma^2_X$

Comment: UM.. o.O YEAH..... I THINK I LIKE THE DUMBED DOWN VERSION OF PAW88789 BETTER. THANK YOU ALL!!!!!!!!!!!